# Block web browsing by older browsers

Tags: firewall, watchguard

Given the vulnerabilities in older versions of IE, I want to enforce a rule that only the latest IE or Firefox is used to browse the web.
I can't ensure that everyone's PC is up to date, so is there a firewall that will let me write a rule to restrict the version of the  browser that can make requests through the firewall?
Our current firewall is from Watchguard

Comment: Squid can do it.. but I'm not sure if you mean outbound user traffic, or inbound foreign traffic.. either way, it doesn't sound like the best way to deal with the problem.

Comment: Talk to your Watchguard vendor or Watchguard themselves.  The only reason for buying (and ongoing licensing of) Watchguard firewalls is that availability of somebody to talk to.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it not possible for IE to determine exact version of browser and I never seen watchguard, but the main idea is to monitor HTTP requests for [User-Agent field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) and analyse it. But it is always better to monitor your network health and update status with tools like WSUS or NAP

Comment: agreed, I would prefer to use WSUS, but not all the PCs are on the domain

Comment: It is indeed better to monitor your network health centrally, but blocking old user-agents (and the ability to block user-agents of known malware) is pretty useful.  You'll get flack from managers who are suddenly unable to browse the web when you do this, so you'll want to warn people before implementing this in order to cover yourself.